# Pygame Splash Screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to add a start screen to pygame but I can't get it to work, here is the code:

```
def game_intro():
    intro = true
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    gamedisplay.fill(WHITE)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('Arial',155)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("test", largeText)
    textRect.centre = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gamedisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
File "/Users/harrisonj11/NetBeansProjects/game_test_jakob/src/game_test_jakob.py", line 188, in <module>
        game_intro()
      File 

"/Users/harrisonj11/NetBeansProjects/game_test_jakob/src/game_test_jakob.py", line 172, in game_intro
        intro = true
    NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace:

```
intro = true
```

with

```
intro = True
```

Comment: thanks that seems to have worked, but it just comes up with a blank scren now

Comment: Please ask another question for the blank splash screen, and provide a minimal code example that we can run so it is easier to help you.
The answer addressed the error trace you posted; if you are satisfied, you can consider accepting it.

Comment: `gamedisplay.fill(WHITE)` is likely the reason you get a white screen; then you probably must refresh it or swap the buffers.